# What argument did Paul Kretschmer use for Illyrian being a satem language?

Tags: indo-european

> Kretschmer identified both Illyrian and Messapic as satem languages due to the change from IE *o* to *a*.
>
> [Illyrian language - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illyrian_language)

That sounds like complete nonsense to me. How does the argument go?

How does he know that PIE 'o' always changed into 'a' in Illyrian? I have studied Croatian toponyms quite a bit, and a generally accepted etymology is that *Colapis*, the ancient name for the Kupa river, meant "*winding water*", that "*col*" (winding) comes from *kwol (an ablaut of *kwel, meaning *to turn*), so, if that's true, not all '*o*'-s changed to '*a*' in Illyrian.

And even if we take for granted 'o' changed to 'a' in Illyrian, how does it follow that Illyrian is a satem language?

Comment: How do you know that Kretschmer had the beliefs attributed to him on Wikipedia a half century after he died? Did you find an actual article written by Kretschmer: or are you asking for a bibliographic source, e.g. "what are the writings of Paul Kretschmer?".

Comment: That entire Wikipedia article is really, really poorly written. A lot of it contradicts itself, and some parts don’t make any sense at all. **If** its representation of Kretschmer’s identification is accurate – and given the state of the article, that’s a big if – then it’s bunkum, yes. The change of _o_ to _a_ may have some level of correlation with the centum/satem split, but it is most certainly not a reliable predictor of whether a language is centum or satem.

Comment: certainly if that is Kretschmer's argument it's bogus. An o > a shift is also found in Germanic, Tocharian, and Anatolian. Preservation of the distinction between o & a is only found within centum (specifically Greek, Latin, and Celtic), but the two shifts clearly do not always coincide

Comment: cp. Old English *collenferhþ* "proud," (full of *ferhþ*), German *Quelle* "well, source", *Freudenquell* (offspring), or differently the *Waal*, *Wacal* in Roman sources. Use the source, Luke. The idae that \*kʷol- is *generally* agreed on has little merrit if hardly anyone knows anything about it for lack of attestation while Roman scribes are known to hear what they want to hear.

Comment: To the opposite however, "roman. /ǎ/ [...] in slav. /o/" in loans, cf. pòreč (Bichlmeier, Sava). See also *Labe*, *interlape* etc.